# How to use Code First Migrations When Domain Models in Separate Project from WebUI?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a VS 2017 solution with 2 .Net Core 1.1 projects, 1 is just a class library containing all of my domain models and the other is the actual MVC web application containing the contexts (the ApplicationDbContext & one I created) & all of the EFCore assemblies.  I'm trying to enable & use migration on the context I created but having trouble being that the context is in the WebUI project and the models are in the class project.  Upon 1st execution of Add-Migration command, I got this error about my target project didn't match my migrations assembly, so I figured out how to get around that by changing the migration assembly in Startup.cs.  Add-Migration ended up working but the migration file was created in the class project where the EFCore assemblies are not referenced, thus giving an error on the migration file.  I thought maybe I'd try and trick it by moving the file to my WebUI project to update the database, but then figured that may not work & there has to be an easier way of doing this.  Does anyone know how to setup code first migrations for EFCore to keep track of modifications and update the database when my domain models are in another project?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Hopefully this isn't too vague.  If more info is needed, I'll be all too happy to post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding the question correctly, but have you tried referencing your domain project in your webUI?

Comment: Yes, my domain is referenced in my WebUI project. What is it that you don't understand so I can explain it?

Comment: no I think I misread your question, you were being clear. I was in this situation before, and ended up just moving the DbContext to my Domain project, and then used Repository Model in my WebAPI project. This had the benefit of keeping all entity models in Domain, and View/API models in WebAPI. Not sure if this would a be suitable solution for you.

Comment: Yeah, my DbContext is already in my WebUI project which has all of the EF7 references.  I was thinking of moving the migration file that was created in the Domain project from execution of the Add-Migration command to the WebUI project, then trying to update the database from there, but I figured if that worked, I'd have to do that every time I changed one of the models, which I don't really forsee doing too much since they're pretty much the way I need them.  But I know there has to be a simpler, smoother way to do this.  Trickery will prevail, if nothing else.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: no problem, but I think there was a misunderstanding, I meant to say move your DbContext to Domain project, then just Add-Migration/Update-Database in Domain. WebUI doesn't need to have it's own DbContext, it can just consume Domain's whenever needed. That way all your models, migrations, and Db Access layer are in Domain, and WebUI just references Domain.DbContext/Domain.UoW whenever needed.

Comment: Nope, didn't misunderstand, but to do that I'll have to add the EF7 assemblies to my Domain project.  They are currently only in my WebUI project, which is why I said it opposite the way you mentioned.  Think I'll add the assemblies in the Domain project and move the context like you suggested and give that a whirl.  Take care.